# searching in binary tree in c when data gets larger

Tags: c

```
void *node_search(node_t *root, void *key) {
    node_t** curr = &root;
    int outcome;
    static int comparison = 0;
    while (*curr){
        outcome = strcmp(key, (*curr)->name);
        comparison++;
        printf("%d", outcome);
        if(outcome<0) {
            curr = &(*curr)->left;
        } else {
            if(outcome == 0){
               printf("%s---> ", key);
               printf("%d number of comparisions\n", comparison);   
               comparison=0;
               return (*curr)->movie;
            }
            curr = &(*curr)->right;
        } 

    }

           printf("%s---> ", key);
           printf("%d number of comparisions but NOT FOUND\n", comparison);
           comparison = 0;


    return (*curr);
}
```

when the number of data is small it finds what i need to find pefectly

but when the same data set but larger in size gets used it prints out not found

why is this??

here's my insertion to tree

```
node_t *insert_node(node_t *root, node_t *new)
{
    node_t** curr = &root;
    while (*curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(new->name, (*curr)->name) < 0) {
            curr = &(*curr)->left;
        } else {
            curr = &(*curr)->right;
        }
    }

    *curr = new;

    return root;
}
```

Comment: It's more likely the data values rather than the data size that is affecting the result. So please provide sample data of at least a case that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In `insert_node`, you should be passing in `root` as a `node_t **` instead of a `node_t *`.  Otherwise, if you have an empty tree the root node won't get created.  Also, be sure to initialize `root` to NULL in your `main`.

Since you'll be passing in the address of your root pointer, `insert_node` doesn't need to return anything.

```
void insert_node(node_t **root, node_t *new)
{
    node_t** curr = root;
    while (*curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(new->name, (*curr)->name) < 0) {
            curr = &(*curr)->left;
        } else {
            curr = &(*curr)->right;
        }
    }

    *curr = new;
}

int main()
{
    node_t *root = NULL;
    ...
    insert_node(&root, node1);
    insert_node(&root, node2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The root is being returned by `insert_node` so is presumably being assigned back to root in the caller.